# How to export specific routes over a peered vpc connection in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql, google-vpc

I have the following VPC connectivity in google cloud:

VPC A <===== VPC Peering connection =====> VPC B (google managed VPC for cloudsql vi a private service connect)

VPC A route table:

| Destination | Next hop |
| --- | --- |
| 10.2.4.0/24 | VPN connection 1 |
| 10.2.5.0/24 | VPN connection 2 |

I want to export specific custom routes(`for eg 10.2.4.0/24`) from VPC A to VPC B, but on the VPC peering options, it shows only `export custom routes` option. Is there a way to export specific routes? Google cloud's `auth-cloudsql-proxy` seems to be the way to go, but I wanted to know about this from other folks.

Comment: Do you try to reach a Cloud SQL private IP through a peered VPC?

Comment: hey @guillaumeblaquiere, yup, that's what I was trying.

Comment: 1) You cannot control the routes for VPC peering. 2) VPC peering is not transitive. 3) You could implement a Host Project for Peering to solve the Cloud SQL routing issue. 4) I strongly recommend deploying Cloud SQL Auth Proxy to handle secure connections to Cloud SQL. Also, the proxy is more resilient (immune) to future VPC networking changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the best solution is to set up a SOCKS5 proxy in the intermediary VPC between the client and your Cloud SQL instance. The Cloud SQL Auth proxy supports chaining through a SOCKS5 proxy, a protocol that forwards TCP packets to a destination IP address. This method allows the intermediate node to forward encrypted traffic from the Cloud SQL Auth proxy to the destination Cloud SQL instance.

The SOCKS5 support can be configured by specifying a SOCKS url in an ALL_PROXY environment variable when invoking the Cloud SQL Auth proxy. Users can direct the Cloud SQL Auth proxy to use a SOCKS5 proxy with the following command:

```
ALL_PROXY=socks5://localhost:8000 cloud_sql_proxy -instances=$INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:5432
```

Comment: Thanks for this input. I found out the client VPC and the intermediate VPC were connected via HA-VPN , hence, I could establish connectivity by using cloudsql proxy in the intermediate VPC. Got to know about the SOCKS5 alternative. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the proxy in the intermediate VPC - the Cloud SQL proxy is intended to be a client side proxy, and connections to the proxy are unencrypted.

Comment: That's a valid point. Does SOCKS5 solve that problem?

Comment: Yes, because the Cloud SQL Auth proxy encrypts all data between it and the Cloud SQL instance. The SOCKS5 proxy only redirects the traffic from one place to another, but it's encrypted the whole way through.

Answer (score 2):

When you peer a VPC, you can only export (or import) the custom routes. You can't select these one that you want, and those that you don't want.

In addition, all the subnet from 1 VPC will be automatically routable in the other VPC after the peering.

However, the [peering isn't transitive](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#restrictions). that means you can't achieve that

```
VPC A -> PEERING -> VPC B -> PEERING -> VPC Managed by Google (Cloud SQL)
```

The VM (or VPN or whatever landing) in the VPC A won't be able to reach the Cloud SQL database on the private IP (with or without the Cloud SQL proxy, it's a network limitation)

A solution is to set up a proxy VM in the VPC B that help you to jump and pass through this limitation. The Kurtisvg answer is great for this workaround.

You can also prefer a Shared VPC instead of a VPC peering.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like the only option. Coming from AWS, I thought it would be possible here as well :). Curious to know why google chose not to use the existing VPC for cloudsql for private connections.

Comment: Simply because the Cloud SQL instances are hosted in the Google Cloud managed VPC (the serverless world)